# How to edit the labels of the donut chart using ggplot2 of R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, donut-chart

I am trying to create a donut chart using the following codes -

```
library (ggplot2)
data = data.frame (
 category = c("No/Minimal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Moderately Severe", "Severe"),
 count = c(27,21,179,67,32))

data$fraction = data$count/sum(data$count)
data$ymax = cumsum(data$fraction)
data$ymin = c(0, head(data$ymax, n=-1))

data$category = factor (data$category, levels = c("No/Minimal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Moderately Severe", "Severe"))

p = ggplot(data, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=category)) +
 geom_rect() +
 coord_polar(theta="y") +
 xlim(c(2, 4))
p

dep<-p + scale_fill_brewer("Depression Level") + theme_void() +
 theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) + theme(legend.position=c(.5, .5)) + ggtitle("") +
 theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
 theme(axis.text=element_blank()) +
 theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
 theme(legend.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold")) +
 theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"))
dep
dep+geom_label(aes(label=paste(fraction*100,"%"),x=3.5,y=(ymin+ymax)/2),inherit.aes = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE)
```

It gives me an output like this - 
[image]

But I want to present the percentage like this 9.8%, 54.9%, 20.5%, 6.4% ...

what should I add or change here in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `round` with 3 digits in your `geom_label`?

```
geom_label(aes(label=paste(round(fraction, digits = 3)*100,"%"),x=3.5,y=(ymin+ymax)/2),inherit.aes = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE)
```

To make bold and larger, change `fontface` and `size`:

```
geom_label(aes(label=paste(round(fraction, digits = 3)*100,"%"),x=3.5,y=(ymin+ymax)/2),inherit.aes = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE, 
               fontface = "bold", size = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But could it be possible to make the text of the "percentage label" a little bit larger and give a "bold" effect?

Comment: Yes - you can make it bold (`fontface`) and use `size` to make larger - see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, dear! Appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Ben, Is there any way to change the color of this plot without editing the `scale_fill_brewer()` function? I have tried `scale_color_manual`. But nothing happened.

Comment: Did you try `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_color_manual`?

Comment: Yeah. I have tried `scale_fill_manual`. But it says -

`Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the
existing scale.
Error in !self$na.translate : invalid argument type`

Comment: Did you remove `scale_fill_brewer`? You should remove that, and replace with `scale_fill_manual`. I tried it with your code and it works.

Comment: Like this: `scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "yellow", "orange", "pink", "purple"))`

Answer (score 3):

Change `label` in the last line to:

```
paste0(formatC(100*fraction, digits=1, format="f"), "%")
```

```
dep + geom_label(aes(label=paste0(formatC(100*fraction, digits=1, format="f"), "%"),x=3.5,y=(ymin+ymax)/2),
               inherit.aes = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: label]